3D plotting with equations containing equal signs?
I have a few problems with 3D plotting, namely equations with equal signs in it. For example, x^2 + y^2 = 1 yields Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator '=' or '=1'. Is there anyway around this problem without tediously inverting the equation(s)?
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[mesh]{x^2 + y^2 = 1};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The equation I'm trying to plot is this one:
(x² + 2y³ + z² - 1)³ - x²z³ - (y²z³)/10  = 0

via the heart equation. Trying to expand and writing it in terms of x and y would be too complex.

Not really,  You could write a program to compute (approximate) numerical solutions and store the values in a table.  You might have better results with parametric solutions based on polar coordinates, depending on the shape of the solution.
